# Copy unique IDs from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to copy unique IDs from one sheet to another.

The code is giving me

> Method 'Range' of object  '_worksheet' failed

```vb
Private Sub PopulateUniqueIds()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
lastrows2 = GetLastRow(ws2)

ws2.Range("C4:C" & CStr(lastrows2)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws1.Range("B9"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

ws2 and ws1 are WorkSheet objects.

I get this error:

```
ws2.Range("C4:C" & CStr(lastrows2)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws1.Range("B9"), Unique:=True
```

Comment: Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and, especially [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: where is your `GetLastRow` Sub (or Function) ? where do you define `lastrows2` ? Also `CStr(lastrows2)` should be `CLng(lastrows2)`

Comment: I have this GetLastRow which is passing me lastrow number as long and im converting it to String and concatinating it

Comment: But that is not giving me a problem

Comment: There is no one who can answer this query? Amazing!

Comment: you have not provided any useful information, for instance on what line are you getting this error ? Also, change your `ws2.Range("C4:C" & CStr(lastrows2))` to `ws2.Range("C4:C" & CLng(lastrows2))` , as row is either `Integer` or `Long`, definitely not a `String` !

Comment: @ShaiRado Op's said `lastrows2` is already of `Long` type.

Comment: @user7360443 (and hoping I'm not late), what's the value of `lastrows2` when throwing the error?

Comment: It is giving me a value 10, but again im saying the problem is not there. Range object is a problem

Answer (score 1):

I believe the *destination* `range` is already filled with a value not corresponding to the one it's going to be filled with

so it's best to clear it:

```
ws1.Range("B9").ClearContents
ws2.Range("C4:C" & CStr(lastrows2)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws1.Range("B9"), Unique:=True
```

Comment: step through your code and query relevant variable in Immediate Window to see what's going on. For instance you could query `?ws2.Range("C4:C" & CStr(lastrows2)).Address, ws1.Range("B9").Address` and press return

Comment: @user7360443, did you get through it?

Comment: Nope, could not, I think its not possible to use it across the sheets. Try for some other solution.

Comment: It IS possible to use across sheets as I myself can experiment with your very code. If you get a "Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed error." then there's something wrong in the range definition. Have you stepped through your code and queryied relevant variables in the immediate window?